# "Steve has won the first prize in the wall painting competition" Change the voice

Tags: grammar

The title says it all. This question had come up in my exam and I wrote the answer as follows

"*The first prize in the wall painting competition has been won by Steve***"

But the teacher though, says that its  "*The first prize has been won by Steve in the wall painting competition*" (I feel it doesn't sound right)

I am confused now, though I was confident of the answer.
*Please help me. Thanks*

Comment: I have a slight preference for your phrasing.  Additionally, here in the US (not sure about UK) we wouldn't say "THE first prize..." - we'd just say "First prize..."

Comment: Your answer is good. However you have the situation where the boss (sorry, teacher) had a different result in mind, without the flexibility to say yours is still correct.

Comment: What @YosefBaskin said. Anyone who thinks only *one* sequence is "correct" has no business teaching English. Find a different teacher, if you can.

Comment: I've a largish preference for your answer. The other on show (and it's not the only other possibility) is not ungrammatical, but _is_ more clumsy. The definite article is (per se) optional, but as it's given in the original, will doubtless be preferred in the passivisation. //// Actually, different variants can be used to give different stresses: "In which discipline did Steve win first prize?" ...  "The first prize has been won by Steve in _the wall painting competition_."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks, looks like both the answers are correct, but with different perspectives.

Comment: @cruthers Oh, I'm an Indian.. could you please tell me what's wrong with using "the" to start the sentence please?

Comment: @YosefBaskin I mean teachers here in my school (In India) are such irrespective of the subject
The question was for 1 mark in the test.. I got a half but that doesn't matter, I should be perfect in the language:)

Comment: It's just idiomatic here to say that someone "won first prize" or "won second prize..." If you watch an awards show, the announcement would be "First prize goes to..." and not "The first prize."  I don't know that there is a logic to it, but it would sound bizarre to say, "I won the first prize in the competition."  That almost sounds like there is a sequence of prizes, and you won the first one that was announced.  What you intend to say, I assume, is that you beat everyone, i.e. came in first = "won first prize."

Comment: @cruthers In the UK, perhaps 'won the first prize in ...' is becoming somewhat old-fashioned, but is still used to add stress to the feat and/or the fact that prizes were on offer (won the first prize at the Lower Hogswater Tin Bath and Cardboard Boat Event).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, interesting... I suppose I can imagine John Cleese announcing that Nigel Incubator-Jones has won "the first prize" in the Upper-Class Twit of the Year competition.

Comment: @cruthers Three years running....  Hopefully someone will stop him soon.

Comment: In BrE, "the" on the decline since 1940: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=won+the+first+prize+in%2Cwon+first+prize+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=29&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwon%20the%20first%20prize%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwon%20first%20prize%20in%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Your teacher's version introduces more ambiguity.  Imagine a situation like the Olympics where multiple events are being held concurrently.  The announcers are waiting to see who will receive the first medal of the games.  Suppose Steve gets the Bronze in wall-painting.  The announcers could say, "The first prize [of the games] has been won by Steve in the wall-painting competition."

Comment: @Jim umm did you intentionally add both "[of the games]" and wall painting competition in the same sentence?

Comment: @cruthers  Thank you very much for helping me with my doubt :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you very much for helping me with my doubt :)